# Troubleshooting division by zero warning

Tags: php

I want to display like and unlike vote with count. my code is given below but it displays Warning: division by zero in filename.php.

```
<?php
include("db.php");

if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=mysql_escape_String($_POST['id']);
$name=mysql_escape_String($_POST['name']);

mysql_query("update messages set $name=$name+1 where id='$id'");

$result=mysql_query("select up,down from messages where id='$id'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

$up_value=$row['up'];
$down_value=$row['down'];
$total=$up_value+$down_value;

$up_per=($up_value*100)/$total;
$down_per=($down_value*100)/$total;
?>
<div style="margin-bottom:10px">
<b>Ratings for this blog</b> ( <?php echo $total; ?> total)
</div>
<table width="700px">

<tr>
<td width="30px"></td>
<td width="60px"><?php echo $up_value; ?></td>
<td width="600px"><div id="greebar" style="width:<?php echo $up_per; ?>%"></div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="30px"></td>
<td width="60px"><?php echo $down_value; ?></td>
<td width="600px"><div id="redbar" style="width:<?php echo $down_per; ?>%"></div></td>
</tr>

</table>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: "Do this for me" questions are frowned upon, you're supposed to show http://WhatHaveYouTried.com and ask for directions. On-topic, the only division you have is with `/$total`, so it's clear that `$total` equals to `0`. You have to find out why this behavior happens and prevent it from dividing by 0. Simple as that.

Comment: Have you considered that $total may be zero?

Answer (score 0):

check the variable `$total` before you use in division operation

e.g. `if ($total != 0)` then do the division opration

Answer (score 0):

If a resource has not been up-voted or down-voted, it will result in a division by zero there:

```
$up_per=($up_value*100)/$total;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($total !== 0) {
  $up_per = ($up_value*100)/$total;
  $down_per = ($down_value*100)/$total;
} else {
  // what do you want to show when there is no votes.
  $up_per = 0;
  $down_per = 0;
}
```